# Notation for "S partitions into S1, S2"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there an established notation for *"$S = S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \ldots$; where $S_i$ are pairwise disjoint"*? In other words, $S$ partitions into the subsets $S_i$.

I have seen a shorthand for *"$S_1, S_2$ intersect"*: $S_1 \bigotimes S_2$. I'm pretty sure someone has come up with something similar for partition.

Comment: What are you looking for? Notation?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the title, the question and the tags.

Comment: You have finite sets or infinite?

Comment: Finite, but I imagine there wouldn't be much difference in notation even if they were infinite... (as long as the partition contains finitely many sets).

Comment: You can just "invent" your own notation if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not uncommon to use the symbols $\uplus$ or $\sqcup$ to denote disjoint unions, but there are two different interpretations of that:

- First, $A\uplus B$ could mean the union of two sets that are *isomorphic* (in whichever way appropriate) to $A$ and $B$ but with their elements renamed to guarantee they will always be disjiont.
- Alternatively, $A\uplus B$ could mean the ordinary union of $A$ and $B$, *except* that the operation is considered undefined if $A$ and $B$ are not *already* disjoint, similar to how $\frac a b$ is considered undefined if $b$ happens to be zero.

If you're using the second interpretation, you can simply say,
$$ S = S_1 \uplus S_2 \uplus \cdots \uplus S_n$$
Since $\uplus$ in this interpretation is associative and commutative whenever it's defined, the whole right-hand side is defined if and only if the $S_i$s are *pairwise* disjoint. As this all works out nicely, an indexed variant will also make sense:
$$ S = \biguplus_{i=1}^n S_i $$

However, even though these usages are not *novel*, they're not what you'd call *established* either, so you can't rely on a reader automatically knowing what you mean by it. You'd need to tell your reader about it explicitly, perhaps in an initial "notation" section of whatever you're writing.

Comment: Especially for the first, I've also seen it with a "dot" like $S_1 \dot{\cup} S_2$. It might by a "German" notation, see eg https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunkte_Vereinigung (which is the German version of the disjoint union page). It says that the one with the dot is used *to convey* that the sets are disjoint while $\sqcup$ is used for to make it so that  the sets are disjoint.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to MSE. The answer to your question is **NO**

You can write it as $$S = \bigcup_{i = 1}^{n}S_i$$

where $S_i \cap S_m = \varnothing$ for all $1 \leqslant m < i \leqslant n$. Note here: $i \not = m$. Hope this helps.

Note: You can also write it as

$$S = \bigcup_{S_i \cap S_m = \varnothing}^{}S_i$$

Comment: That sounds rather authoritative. Do you have a proof?

Comment: What do you mean by proof?

Comment: Proof that there is no such notation. When you say **NO** in bold all-caps, you must be sure you are right.

Comment: You can't prove a notation for something doesn't exist. Because if you can't find it, you can always just make it up yourself. Then it exists.

Comment: I've seen people writing $\sqcup S_i$ to show the empty intersections. Though this is not what disjoint unions really mean, readers usually can get the idea.

Comment: To add to this answer, if the context makes which sets $S_i$ you are taking the union, you can just write {$S_i\cap S_j=\emptyset$} under the union, and you don't need to write out the upper/lower indexes explicitly.

Comment: @justadzr I've seen (and used) that notation to mean disjoint union too. Given the correct context, it could be able to mean "pairwise disjoint".

Comment: @BooleanWick I'll leave that up to you :)